# Spring security not securing methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying out Spring security and I annotated some methods of my RestController with @PreAuthorize.
However, I can access all of them without being authenticated.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Security configuration, imported by root-context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans ...>  
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/service/public/**" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/service/user/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/service/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
         <authentication-provider> <user-service> <user name="admin" password="admin" 
            authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" /> <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" 
            /> </user-service> </authentication-provider>    
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

My service:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class Service {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/public/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String storeEntityPublic(@PathVariable String name) {
        String result = "Hello " + name + ", I am saving on the db. (PUBLIC)";
        return result;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String storeEntityUserOrAdmin(@PathVariable String name) {
        String result = "Hello " + name
                + ", I am saving on the db. (USER OR ADMIN)";
        return result;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String storeEntityAdmin(@PathVariable String name) {
        String result = "Hello Admin " + name
                + ", I am saving on the db. (ADMIN ONLY)";
        return result;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Move `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />` to the context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. As with all AOP things they apply only to beans in the same context. You have defined it in the root context so only beans in the root context will be considered. Your controller is part of the child (`DispatcherServlet`) so it doesn't know anything about it.

Comment: Thanks, that was the point. Please move it as answer, so that I can accept it.